# Limit of the composition function $\sin(\cos(x))/\cos(x)$ at $\pi/2$ in Apostol Exercises 3.8

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, alternative-proof, epsilon-delta

In Apostol calculus exercise there is a bunch of exercises where we need to find a limit of a composite function. One example is this:

$\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)}$

Well, intuitively we simply take $\cos(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \pi/2$. Then $\lim_\limits{x \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(\cos(x))}{\cos(x)} = 1$, since the limit of $\sin(x)/x$ is 1 as $x \rightarrow 0$. Multiple online solutions suggest the same without any explanation.

How to show this rigorously? In Apostol, there is a proof that composition of two continuous functions is continuous at any $x = p$. However, there is no proof about general limits. Moreover, we know that $\sin(x)/x$ is not even defined at $0$. How is it allowed to substitute $\cos(x) \rightarrow 0$ into this outer sine then?

PS. L'Hopital rule has not been specified yet. The only available option is delta-epsilon arguments, and simplest limit rules: sum, difference, product, and division. Squeezing limit theorem can be used (proved before). Plus sin(x)/x limit at 0 has been proven with squeezing limit theorem.

Comment: You can check that $f(x)=\sin(x)/x$ has a continuous extension to $x=0$ with $f(0)=0$. Then you can apply the composition rule.

Comment: @CalvinKhor, However, this extension is not specified (allowed?) in the exercise. And it would be better to understand the work with general limits (from where continuity follows).

Comment: Can you use the rules of L'Hospital?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, no. The derivative is the next section. The only tools available at this step are delta-epsilon arguments.

Comment: For $y$ small, put $x = \pi/2 +y$, then $ \cos x = cos ( \pi/2 + y ) = - \sin y$?

Comment: You can substitute $$t=\cos(x)$$ and for $x$ tends to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ so $t$ tends to zero.

Comment: $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, I do not think this is valid conclusion, since t is not really a function output, but a limit. Is there some proof about substitution of limits somewhere in delta-epsilon terms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Plus sin(x)/x limit at 0 has been proven with squeezing limit theorem.

OK, then you're basically done. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta$ so that $|(\sin y)/y-1 | < \epsilon$ if $0<|y|<\delta$. Now choose $0<\delta_1<1$ such that
$$ 0<|x-\pi/2| < \delta_1 \implies |\cos x | < \delta.$$
This implies
$$ 0<|x-\pi/2| < \delta_1 \implies \left|\frac{\sin\cos x }{  \cos x} - 1\right| < \epsilon.$$

Further,

> In Apostol, there is a proof that composition of two continuous functions is continuous at any $x=p$
> . However, there is no proof about general limits.

You will find that the proof for limits is nearly the same as the proof for continuous functions, I recommend it as an exercise for you.

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly the proof I wanted. 
I think I can easily extend this to the general limit theorem - I just assume that the inner function is continuous everywhere, then your proof becomes the proof of the general limit case! Thanks.

Comment: @John  You don't need continuity anywhere, just need the two limits to exist, and the domains/codomains need to match up. For instance if the inner function was $\cos : \mathbb [0,\pi/2) \to \mathbb R$ then it still works

Comment: We should make $\cos x$ never be equal to 0 by making $\delta_1$ < $\frac{π}{2}$ , or $\frac{\sin \cos x}{\cos x}$ will get error .

Comment: You are correct but usually issues that pop up when delta or epsilon is too large aren't very important :) I'll fix the answer @Mathematicianwannabe

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the L'Hospital rule.

$$\lim _{x\to \pi /2} \frac {\sin (\cos x)}{\cos x} =\lim _{x\to \pi/2} \frac {\cos (\cos x)(-\sin x)}{-\sin x}=1$$

Comment: I cannot - L'Hopital rule has not been specified yet. The only available option is delta-epsilon arguments, and simplest limit rules: sum, difference, product, and division. Squeezing theorem can be used. Plus sin(x)/x limit at 0 has been proven with squeezing limit theorem.